# PHPStorm Clone GitHub Error - Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

PHPStorm Version: 10.0.3

I'm setting up a brand new repository on GitHub and trying to check it out from PHPStorm.  However no matter what I try to checkout will fail.  I have tried on my personal GitHub account and work one and get the following error screens.  The credentials are working correctly in the VCS->GitHub settings and it even prefills the available projects just fine in the drop down.

I have also tried to checkout other projects that I know do not have any issues but the same errors occur as shown.  I can access them just fine with GitHub desktop but would prefer the built in VCS system...  it seems to be a specific PHPStorm config issue of some kind.

[image]
[image]

Comment: is there a private repo ?

Comment: there is a private repo but I can not get it to work on any of them, public or private.  as a side note I was able to load up PHPStorm 9 and clone the project and then open PHPStorm 10 and it upgraded the project.  But that doesn't explain the issue unfortunately.

Comment: I actually replaced my motherboard and had to reinstall my computer. The latest version worked with no issues now.  I'm going to guess it has something to do with "Upgrading" from a previous version of PHPStorm to the latest.  The error is no longer happening.

Answer (score 1):

I think is the Git repository URL, check out mine

[PhpStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBNFd.png)

Comment: I will try tonight, what version PHPStorm is that just for reference?

Comment: It is 10.0.1, i'll update mine to check if still works